# Replacement for MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer in iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8, mpmusicplayercontroller

I'm looking to play music in the background, and also handle iTunes Match content. The iPodMusicPlayer of MPMusicPlayerController handles both, but is deprecated in iOS 8. Anyone know what APIs or frameworks they are looking for us to move to to handle both of my requirements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer]` instead. See here for more detail : https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS80APIDiffs/index.html

Comment: The link doesn't really provide any additional info though. Maybe add a new one when this class becomes documented?

Comment: I actually test it to see what's the real modification (and I haven't play a lot with iPodMusicPlayer by the past but I assume nothing really change. We'll see but the actual documentation for iPod Library is still valid.

Comment: While it is not documented as of yet, looking at the latest headers has a deprecation note of "Use +systemMusicPlayer instead." on the iPodMusicPlayer method. Thanks!